# Angular UI Bootstrap Carousel Fullscreen

Tags: angularjs, fullscreen, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am currently trying to get the Angular UI Bootstrap Carousel to be the full length of my page. I have it on the outer most div, but it only extends the width of the page, and stops vertically at the start of the next div.

Here is the ctrl (just stores the images in an array)

```
$scope.myInterval = 5000;


 var slides = $scope.slides = [
  { image:"http://www.bestfon.info/images/joomgallery/originals/animales_7/dog_with_glasses_20140320_2017987799.jpg"
 },
 {
  image:"http://www.animalpictures1.com/data/media/177/dog_2560x1440.jpg"
 }
  ];
```

Here is the html(carousel is at the top, but the div its in closes at the very bottom)

```
<div>
 <carousel interval="myInterval" id="carouselID">
      <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}">

      </slide>
     </carousel>
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
   <!-- <div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="../images/barkIT.png" alt="">
   </div> -->
    <div class="col-md-12" id="profileIMG">
     <img src="{{owner.image}}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <h1>{{owner.name}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="contactInfo">
     <p><img src="../images/email.png" alt="">{{owner.email}}    <img src="../images/telephone_black.png" alt="">{{owner.phone}}</p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="socialNav">
     <a href="https://twitter.com/{{owner.twitter}}"><img src="../images/Twitter-icon.png" alt=""></a>
     <a href="https://instagram.com/{{owner.instagram}}"><img src="../images/Instagram-icon.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <a href="#/owners/{{owner._id}}/edit">Edit Profile</a> | <a ng-click="deleteOwner(owner._id)">Delete Profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>

<hr>
 <div>
  <div class="col-md-12" id="dogTag">
   <img src="../images/tag_add.png" alt="" ng-click="dogAdd = true">
  </div>
   <div  class="col-md-12" ng-show="dogAdd">
    <form ng-submit="createDog(newDog)">
     <!-- <div class="col-md-3"> -->
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="newDog.name" placeholder="Name">
     <!-- </div> -->
     <!-- <div class="col-md-3"> -->
      <input type="url" ng-model="newDog.image"placeholder="Image URL">
     <!-- </div> -->
     <!-- <div class="col-md-3"> -->
      <input type="text" ng-model="newDog.type" placeholder="Breed">
     <!-- </div> -->
     <!-- <div class="col-md-3"> -->
      <input type="number" ng-model="newDog.weight" placeholder="Weight">
    <!--  </div>
       </div> -->
   <!-- <div class="col-md-12"> -->
      <button type="submit" ng-click="dogAdd = false">Create</button>
   <!-- </div> -->
    </form>
 </div>
<div  id="dogCard" class="col-md-12">

 <div ng-repeat="dog in dogs">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3>{{dog.name}}</h3>
   <p>{{dog.type}}</p>
   <p>{{dog.weight}}</p>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-4" id=dogProfileIMG>
   <img src="{{dog.image}}" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3><u>Reminders</u></h3>
   <div id="reminderList" ng-repeat="reminder in dog.reminders">
    <ul>
     <li><img src="../images/paw.png" alt="">{{reminder}}</li>
   </div>
 <button ng-click="reminderAdd = true">Add Reminder</button>
 <form ng-submit="createReminder(dog, reminder)" ng-show="reminderAdd">
  <input type="text" ng-model="reminder" placeholder="Enter Reminder">
  <button type="submit" ng-click="reminderAdd = false">Add Reminder</button>
 </form>
  </div>
  <hr>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS i have

```
#carouselID{
 height:100%;
 img{
  width:100%;
  opacity:.7;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry what is the issue? http://plnkr.co/edit/5iqP1f?p=preview

Comment: Basically I want my carousel to be the background. but its only displaying at the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

Hi Carousel height is most probably limited to height of the images. You'll have to make your images taller if you want to fill up more of the page :-)